# Push values to array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, list

I have List of items `data and empty array quotations` :

```
   var data = {};
   var quotations = [];
```

I want to fill `quotations` with data values ,Every time i add new data it added successfully but all data values get last value .

for example :

```
 $("#addquotation").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
        var cost =parseFloat( $("#cost").val());
        var notes = $("#notes").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();


        data.Item = itemname;
        data.Cost = cost;
        data.Notes = notes;
        data.Date = date;

        quotations.push(data);
)};
```

for first time i add

> "test,45,testnotes,2016-02-03" Second time i 've added
>   "test2,45.2,testnotes2,2016-02-05"

when i debug i get data as :

> obj(0): "test2,45.2,testnotes2,2016-02-05"
>   obj(1):"test2,45.2,testnotes2,2016-02-05"

it seems it append last version to all data

Please Advice . Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to declare data inside the click handler, if it's declared as a global variable you are basically always modifying and adding the same data object to the array:

```
var quotations = [];

$("#addquotation").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var data = {};
        var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
        var cost =parseFloat( $("#cost").val());
        var notes = $("#notes").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();


        data.Item = itemname;
        data.Cost = cost;
        data.Notes = notes;
        data.Date = date;

        quotations.push(data);
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing the same object reference each time since you declared `data` outside of the click handler.

Change from :

```
var data={};
$("#addquotation").click(function () {
```

To

```
$("#addquotation").click(function () {
     var data={};// declare local variable
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `data` is a global variable and you add a reference to `data` to `quotations`.

When the first value is pushed to `quotations`, `data` and `quotations[0]` refer to the same object. Here is an example of what is happening:

```
var a = {num: 1};
var b = a;
b.num = 2;
console.log(a.num); // prints 2
```

The same thing happens when an object is pushed to an array. `quotations` does not contain a copy of `data`, it contains a reference to `data` so that modifying `data` also modifies `quotations`. To fix this, each element of `quotations` must refer to a different data object. This can be accomplished by defining `data` inside of the function instead of outside.

Replace

```
var data = {};
$("#addquotation").click(function() {
    // populate data, push to quotations
});
```

with

```
$("#addquotation").click(function() {
    var data = {};
    // populate data, push to quotations
});
```